# Exclude if between, but more complex

Tags: javascript, regex

So, i'm trying to make regex, which would parse all global functions declarations, stored in objects, for example, like this `const a = () => {}`

I make something like this:

`/(?:const|let|var)\s*([A-z0-9]+)?\s*=\s(function\s*\(([^)(]+|\((?:[^)(]+|\([^)(]*\))*\))*\)|\(([^)(]+|\((?:[^)(]+|\([^)(]*\))*\))*\)\s*\=\>)\s*\{((?:[^}{]+|\{[^}{]*\}|[^}]|\}(\"|\'|\` `))*)*\}/g`

It work fine, but I got a problem with inner declaration ([link](https://regex101.com/r/6eA0vr/9))

If link don't work:

```
const definedJsFunctionsAsObjectRegex = /(?:const|let|var)\s*([A-z0-9]+)?\s*=\s(function\s*\(([^)(]+|\((?:[^)(]+|\([^)(]*\))*\))*\)|\(([^)(]+|\((?:[^)(]+|\([^)(]*\))*\))*\)\s*\=\>)\s*\{((?:[^}{]+|\{[^}{]*\}|[^}]|\}(\"|\'|\`))*)*\}/g;

const str = `
let f = function(a,b) {
  console.log(gdhfsgdfg);
}

const f2 = (a,b,   d) => { blabla }

let f3 = function(){
  fdgdhgf
}

function test() {
    const inner = (t, b) => { im must be undetected}
    const inner2 = function (a,b) {
        im must be undetected too
    }
}

// here checking for }"
function(fds) { obj = {} return "}" }

function r () { obj = {}; a = []; }

function a(){console.log('a')} function b(){console.log('b')}
`;

let matches = [...str.matchAll(definedJsFunctionsAsObjectRegex)];
console.log(matches)
```

So, any ideas, how to exclude inner functions declarations?

I'm tried negative lookahead (?!), but my experiments did not give the desired result.

Comment: WHY DO YOU WANT TO PARSE JS CODE WITH REGEX?

Comment: Just for experiment

Comment: Your experiment should reveal that regex is *terrible* for this job. You should be using an AST parser or at least something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the multiline operator and change your lookbehind to an anchor like so

```
/^(const|let|var)\s*([A-z0-9]+)?\s*=\s(function\s*\(([^)(]+|\((?:[^)(]+|\([^)(]*\))*\))*\)|\(([^)(]+|\((?:[^)(]+|\([^)(]*\))*\))*\)\s*\=\>)\s*\{((?:[^}{]+|\{[^}{]*\}|[^}]|\}(\"|\'|\`))*)*\}/gm
```

See the output [here](https://regex101.com/r/6eA0vr/10)

Comment: Thanks, it's really helpful